# Bare-metal ARM str instruction behavior in QEMU

Tags: assembly, arm, qemu

## Description

**I'm trying to build a bare-metal application (no OS, no bootloader) and run it in QEMU and am seeing some weird behavior with the `str` instruction not seeming to do anything.**

For some context I just want to inject my program directly into RAM and run it. I'm using a modified bare-metal [linker](https://github.com/umanovskis/baremetal-arm/blob/master/src/04_cenv/linkscript.ld) and [startup.S](https://github.com/umanovskis/baremetal-arm/blob/master/src/04_cenv/startup.s) as an example for laying out the memory and setting up the C environment. I don't really care about *which* ARM platform I'm using so I used the same one from their example, the vexpress-a9 with the cortex-a9 processor.

I modified the start-up file in order to have execution start directly at the start exception vector at `0x0` (which I'm treating as ROM, even though I know it's not). The idea is that the `.text` section gets put here, some set-up happens to set-up the `.data`, `.bss` and stack, and then I branch to `main`.

```
MEMORY
{
    ROM (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 1M
    RAM (rwx): ORIGIN = 0x00400000, LENGTH = 4M
}
```

This actually works in that I can start QEMU, attach a gdb session, and step through the initialization code, but for the set-up that should happen in "RAM" (starting at `0x00400000`) nothing gets initialized at all.

For the bit of assembly below, the idea is that I want to fill the FIQ stack section with `0xFEFEFEFE`. So I set `r1` to the start of the stack, `sp` to the end, and while `r1` < `sp` I populate the address contained within `r1` with the value in `r0` and increment the address in `r1` by 4 bytes.

```
Reset_Handler:
    /* FIQ stack */
    msr cpsr_c, MODE_FIQ
    ldr r1, =_fiq_stack_start
    ldr sp, =_fiq_stack_end
    movw r0, #0xFEFE
    movt r0, #0xFEFE

fiq_loop:
    cmp r1, sp
    strlt r0, [r1], #4   <<<< ISSUE HERE
    blt fiq_loop
```

This does loop correctly for the right number of iterations (the size of the stack), but *nothing* is happening for the `strlt r0, [r1], #4` instruction.

If I inspect before the `str` instruction, `r1` is the start of the stack and the value is `0x0`:

```
>>> p/x $r1                                                                                                                   
$2 = 0x400008                                                                                                                 
>>> x/2hx $r1                                                                                                                 
0x400008:       0x0000  0x0000
```

After I step over the `str` instruction, `r1` has moved 4 bytes, but the memory at the start of the stack is still `0x0`:

```
>>> p/x $r1                                                                                                                   
$3 = 0x40000c 
>>> x/2hx 0x400008                                                                                                            
0x400008:       0x0000  0x0000
```

The memory doesn't get updated, but I *can* directly set values there so I know that it *can* be updated:

```
>>> set *(0x400008)=0x12345678                                                                                                
>>> x/2hx 0x400008                                                                                                            
0x400008:       0x5678  0x1234
```

I'm starting qemu with:

```
    qemu-system-arm \
        -nographic \
        -s \
        -S \
        --no-reboot \
        -machine vexpress-a9 \
        -cpu cortex-a9 \
        -m 12M \
        -device loader,file=out.elf
```

I've compiled with the `-mcpu=cortex-a9` option, and believe I've provided QEMU with enough RAM. I'm really lost as to what's happening here, any help is appreciated.

## Further Debugging

Per request, I've also added clarification on the state of the following entities:

- What is the value of `_fiq_stack_start`?

  > `0x00400008`  <- This is what I expect, as I expect the fiq stack to start after the .data section, which holds 8 bytes
- What is the value of `_fiq_stack_end`?

  > `0x00401008`  <- This is what I expect, as I specified the stack to be 4096 bytes
- What are the contents of `r1` at the moment of the `cmp` instruction?

  > `r1 = 0x00400008` <- This is what I expect, as r1 should contain the start of the stack.
- What are the contents of the sp register?

  > `0x00401008`  <- This is what I expect, as this should be the end of the stack
- What are the the condition code bits at the moment the `strlt` starts?

  > Before the compare `CPSR = 0x40000111` and after the compare `CPSR = 0x80000111`. This is expected b/c the value in `r1` is less than the value of `sp` and the result of a positive signed comparison should put a 1 in bit 31.
- What are the contents of `r0`?

  > `0xfefefefe` <- This is what I expect based on the two `mv` instructions to fill the `r0` register with the value I want to be in the stack.
- What happens if you change the `strlt` to `str`?

  > I actually tested this already, and I got the same behavior.

I've also tried these simple instructions:

```
    mov r0, #0x1234
    mov r3, #0x2
    str r0, [r3] /* Store value of R0 into addr at r3 */
```

And after stepping over each instruction I would expect the value `0x1` held with `r0` to be placed into the memory address of `0x2` held within `r3`. But after inspection it isn't.

```
>>> p/x $r0
$7 = 0x1

>>> p/x $r3
$8 = 0x2

>>> x/2hx $r3
0x2 <_Reset+2>: 0xea00  0x0041
```

It's as if the str instruction is completely ignored.

Comment: To reduce the example further, if you cut out the loop and just do a single `str r0, [r1]`, do you observe the same behavior?

Comment: Your title and text repeatedly say `str` instruction, but that is a `strlt` instruction, which is a store if the signed less-than condition is set. What is the value of `_fiq_stack_start`? What is the value of `_fiq_stack_end`? What are the contents of `r1` at the moment of the `cmp` instruction? What are the contents of the `sp` register? What are the the condition code bits at the moment the `strlt` starts? What are the contents of `r0`? What happens if you change the `strlt` to `str`?

Comment: Should be unrelated, but in your loop, I think you want an unsigned compare instead of signed, so the condition code for `str` and `b` would be `lo` instead of `lt`.

Comment: Why is this assembly question tagged C?

Comment: @EricPostpischil b/c I'm setting up a C environment in assembly, I can remove the tag if its inappropriate.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  I believe `strlt` has the same behavior as `str` except on the condition that the previous compare returned a less than in the `CPSR` register. I'll edit the question to post the values of those things, I have inspected them and they seem correct.

@NateEldredge I took the example from [this baremetal example](https://github.com/umanovskis/baremetal-arm/blob/master/doc/04_cenv.md#setting-up-the-stack), but I can try the unsigned compare.

Comment: Re “I believe `strlt` has the same behavior as `str` except…”: A fundamental tenet of debugging is that at least one thing is not as we think it is, and therefore every belief is subject to testing until we find the culprit.

Comment: Also, the original map file has different addresses.  I am not QEMU expert, but you may need to tell it where RAM is located.  If you write to non-existent RAM, it may return zero.  Writing to non-existent memory may behave differently with `gdb` as it assume the write works and cached it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're correct, I should use more exact language. I don't believe that is the behavior, I had already looked up the behavior of `strlt` and verified that the `lt` suffix only executes the instruction based on the result of a previous signed compare. Additionally, I tried just a str to see what happens and the memory still doesn't get updated. Additionally I've updated the question to add descriptions of the variable states.

Comment: @artlessnoise I'm also not a QEMU expert :( My linker and thus mapfile have different addresses b/c I want slightly different behavior. The example is booting from an SD-card and using u-boot to accomplish that, but I don't want to do that.

I specify the `RAM` address start as `0x00400000` and declare it to be of size 4 MB. I've verified in the mapfile and with `readelf` that this does seem to be the case. I'm also starting QEMU with 12MB fo ram so the address space _should_ exist but yeah I'm not experienced with QEMU.

Comment: Check with qemu trace instead of gdb.

Comment: @Jester I'm not familiar with QEMU very well, is that just `qemu --trace`? This is the [only reference I really found](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/devel/tracing.html).

Comment: I was thinking maybe `-d in_asm,out_asm,cpu,nochain -singlestep` or something like that.

Comment: Supposing that the `CPSR`, `r0`, and `r1` stated in the question now are reports from the debugger immediately before `strlt` is executed, I would expect a `strlt` instruction to store `r0` (`0xfefefefe`) at address `r1` (`0x00400008`). If the debugger does not show that happening, and also does not show it happening with `str` instead of `strlt`, some experiments I would consider are: (a) Examine the bits at the instruction address and check whether they are the encoding of the desired store instruction. (b) Change `r1` to some other value and see if memory there changes…

Comment: … (c) Change the store to a move from `r0` to, say, `r3`, and see if `r3` changes to the expected value. (d) Change the store to a load, use the debugger to put some tell-tale value at `0x00400008`, and see if it is loaded.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'll try each of those. I also tried a simple experiment with `str` which I linked above and it does seem to totally ignore the instruction.

Comment: I am not familiar with qemu configuration, but I would guess that you have not actually succeeded in placing read-write memory at `0x400000`.  The fact that the debugger can write it doesn't necessarily mean anything, as the debugger is part of the emulator and so could be able to do things like modifying ROM.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think you're probably correct. The memory region I was treating as read-write may not be accessible in the qemu emulator, when I switched to a different machine it all just worked.

Comment: why doing a signed less than comparison on an address?  why even use less than or greater use equal or not.  did you try strcc or strlo and what happened there?  strne?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"When I try to store to memory it's as if nothing happens" almost always means "I'm trying to store to somewhere where there isn't actually RAM". Sometimes this is "nothing's there", sometimes this is "there's flash or ROM there so the write is ignored". The root cause is usually "program linked to the wrong addresses".

These addresses:

```
ROM (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 1M
RAM (rwx): ORIGIN = 0x00400000, LENGTH = 4M
```

don't match what QEMU models for the vexpress-a9. The first is OK (address 0 is the remappable area, which QEMU models as "always the flash memory, not guest runtime configurable"), but there is no RAM at 0x00400000 -- this address is inside the flash memory so it is not writeable like RAM.

You should use a linker map which puts the RAM area in what the memory map calls "Local DDR2", which starts at 0x6000_0000. The linker script in the tutorial you started from gets this (sort of) right because it uses 0x6000_0000 and 0x7000_0000 -- though note that that only works because the documentation in that tutorial says to use -m 512M which provides enough RAM to get up to the 0x7000_0000 memory range.

The reason your linker script happens to work on the xilinx-zynq-a9 board is that that board puts its block of RAM at address 0.

The overall thing here that I think is important to understand is that when you're writing a linker script you don't get to choose the addresses arbitrarily. The linker script must be written to match the address map of the board you're going to run the resulting bare-metal binary on, and then that binary won't run on a different board type.

(Incidentally, there is a QEMU bug on this board where we try to map both RAM and flash at address 0 -- I think effectively the flash "wins", so the effect is that the low address area is flash.)

Comment: Thanks @petermaydell. I am incredibly familiar with linker scripts and memory but I've never run anything on an emulated device. Based on the datasheet for the vxexpress-a9 I thought 0x0 mapped to DDR2 RAM, and thus so would 0x00400000 as it fits w/in the 64MB. Do you know of a good reference to investigate the QEMU models?

Comment: Unfortunately the QEMU models are not always very well documented. The general intent is that they should match the hardware. In this particular case we don't implement the support the real board has for changing the mapping of the low part of memory or for having the configuration controller set the mapping based on a text file that it reads before resetting the main CPU, so you just get "always the flash".

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer and got it to work. I switched from using the `vxexpress-a9` machine to the `xilinx-zynq-a9` machine (a different cortex-a9 device) and everything just started working. So I'm now starting it with:

```
    qemu-system-arm \
        -nographic \
        -s \
        -S \
        --no-reboot \
        -machine xilinx-zynq-a9 \
        -cpu cortex-a9 \
        -m 12M \
        -device loader,file=out.elf
```

I believe the issue was that I was injecting the .elf directly into memory at the reset vector, like I wanted, however for the `vxexpress-a9` board this may not be valid. I [found a memory map description](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0448/latest/) which shows that the memory section I was using can be re-mapped, so maybe its not acting as DDR2 RAM? That said, QEMU says it [doesn't model the `SCC`](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/arm/vexpress.html) which is what the documentation says allows for configuration of that memory region. I'm honestly not 100% sure but it does seem that it was the device I was using.

I'm guessing the fact that the example I'm working from uses u-boot to set-up the hardware and load the image from the emulated SD-card means that it works for that example. That must be what the emulated hardware expects, but I don't want to do that.

[image]